# Download emails from office365 in 'company mode' via CLI

Tags: email, downloads, offline, office365

This is my first post on this site, so bare with me if the question is unclear or maybe allready answered (I've looke for several days, but no luck)

Situation:
I need to download an entire mailbox from a bussiness email address (in ex.: my.name@my_company.com).
The email is in office365, and the authorization is Active Directory controlled by company IT department. :-)

I've tried to use OFFLINEIMAP, which worked well up to a certain point, where some folder name got a bit 'out-of-bounds' in the eyes of OFFLINEIMAP :)
This could - of course - be fixed by changing the name of the folder causing the problem, but there seems to be a greater number of those folders.
This might be the time to say, that the mailbox in question is approx 37GB and contains a rather large amount of subfolders...

Does any of You intelligent species ever worked with another way to do this?!?

MUTT can log into the mailbox, but how can I script my way to success, so that all the emails is ending up on my HDD ??

ANY solution is wellcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - I found an answer!!!
:)
Remember, I ONLY wanted to Download emails - not upload anything to the mailbox, or change anything...
I found that MBSYNC could do the job for me :)

sudo apt-get install mbsync

vi ~/.mbsyncrc

paste:

```
IMAPAccount gmail
# Address to connect to
Host TheEmailServer...
User MyUserName4TheMailBox
Pass MyPassWord4TheMailBox
UseIMAPS yes
#SSLType IMAPS
#SSLVersion TLSv1.2
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
PipelineDepth 1
# To store the password in an encrypted file use PassCmd instead of Pass
# PassCmd "gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.mailpass.gpg"
#
# Use SSL
# AuthMechs *
# SSLType IMAPS
# SSLVersions TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
# The following line should work. If get certificate errors, uncomment the two following lines and read the "Troubleshooting" section.
#CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/imap.gmail.com.pem
#CertificateFile ~/.cert/Equifax_Secure_CA.pem

IMAPStore gmail-remote
Account gmail

MaildirStore gmail-local
#Subfolders Verbatim
# The trailing "/" is important
Path ~/.mail/my_local_mailbox_folder/
#Inbox ~/.mail/didnt_work_for_me

Channel gmail
Master :gmail-remote:
Slave :gmail-local:
# Exclude everything under the internal [Gmail] folder, except the interesting folders
#Patterns * ![Gmail]* "[Gmail]/Sent Mail" "[Gmail]/Starred" "[Gmail]/All Mail"
# Or include everything
Patterns *
# Automatically create missing mailboxes, both locally and on the server
Create Both
# Save the synchronization state files in the relevant directory
Sync Pull
SyncState *
```

Then run "mbsync gmail" where 'gmail' is the name from the ~/.mbsyncrc above

Then wait for all the emails to arrive :)

NB: It took a couple of days for me to get them all to complete, and I had to restart the sync a couple of times :)

Please don't forget to 'like' this, if it's usefull to You :)